# How to get onscreen-keyboard when installing Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation, keyboard

I am installing Ubuntu on my system. My keyboard keys are not working. How to get the onscreen keyboard while installing Ubuntu? I want to enter my user name and computer name here:

[image: Username-password installation menu]

So what can I do?

Comment: Ubuntu does have an on screen keyboard but you will not be able to use it till after the install. If your keyboard is not working during the install you need to use another keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

im sorry for late answer, but i just figured it out by pressing "try ubuntu" then enabling Accessbility icon from settings, then installing distro

Answer (score 2):

Another late answer. I swiped up from the bottom and a keyboard appeared.

Comment: This seems to work only on touch devices, not with mouse.